# text if going long then the text field coming to next line how to stop it

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to android development.I am trying to make a text field in which if I type long text the next line should not come.

currently If the text is too long line break is coming and its going to the next line making the height of text field grow.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:hint="@string/edit_message"
          android:inputType="textMultiLine"
          android:gravity="top"/>
```

suggest please.

Comment: the problem is on  android:inputType="textMultiLine" ??

Comment: if you want to avoi d the word-wrap try to make the text scrollable

Comment: Yes..remove the 'inputType="Multiline"'...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` parameter. It makes the EditText to break into a new line if the text is becoming big enough

Answer (score 1):

dear use android:singleLine="true"

Answer (score 1):

You have lot of option to restrict this.

- **android:singleLine="true"** Using this textView always display text in only single line.
- **android:lines="1"** Using this you can hard code the number of line space.
- **android:maxLines="1"** Using this your textview size will grow up to specified number of lines.

Hope this will help you to better understanding....:)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

And add this line

```
android:singleLine="true"
```